# Universal shortcuts for music players

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, music, spotify

Does anyone know if I could create universal short-cuts to perform certain actions? I used to have a keyboard with keys for play, pause, skip... that worked in any music player, but my new keyboard doesn't have that anymore. I could really use some global key short-cuts. If it can't be universal, specific ones for Spotify would work too. :-)

Comment: Here you go: http://www.autohotkey.com/ and no I won't post this as an answser since product recomendations are not on topic.

Comment: @Ramhound recommendations are ok as answers http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330 and http://meta.superuser.com/questions/2592/is-giving-a-shopping-recommendation-prohibited/2600#2600

Comment: @BradPatton - In the future I will simply say **I** don't do software recomendation. There are a few exceptions but I don't think suggesting software I have never used is a productive answer and actually the meta answer suggests I post an answer. Furthermore another **DON"T** is the following `"What's the best XX software" or "I need something that does XX"`which I feel describes this question exactly.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, everyone! I went with the AutoHotKey program and it works wonders! :-D Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/). With it you can:

> Create hotkeys for keyboard, joystick, and mouse. Virtually any key, button, or combination can become a hotkey.

Answer (score 2):

A program like [SharpKeys](http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com) can help you remap seldom used keys such as F12 etc. to media keys such as Play/Pause:

[image: 1]

I've used it successfully with keyboards that lacked special media keys, and it worked fine.