# Disable capslock LEDs light

Tags: keyboard, led, capslock

I'd like to know if there's a way to disable the LED light of my capslock key. I'd like to use it for gaming but everytime I press it the LED turn on and it blinds me.

Comment: Go low tech - use good ol' electrical tape!

Comment: @Karan: beat me to it. Amusingly, I distinctly recall there's a commercial product to do that. Personally, I favour blue tac for that, assuming its a non painted surface

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I also recall seeing a special product for this (I can't remember the name of it)... It was definitely amusing through! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a tool like [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to rebind it to another unused key, which won't allow capslock to be enabled and thus disable the light. I recommend reading the [AutoHotKey Tutorial](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm) for more information on how to get started.

---

For example, I use AutoHotKey to rebind <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>:

```
Capslock::Ctrl
```

Simply place that in a text file with an extension of `.ahk`, double click, and you're off!

Comment: @SavannahTaulbee: If all you're after is key remapping and you aren't using AHK already, [SharpKeys or similar](http://superuser.com/a/601963/138343) can help. These programs use Windows' own key remap mechanism via the registry and do not need a program to be constantly running, as AHK will.

Comment: The capslock key is replaced with success with the ctrl key but this doesn't prevent light goes on.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to remap using Windows PowerToys. Go to keyboard manager and remap it to some other key that is supported by your game. This will disable the toggle option and you can use the new remapped value.